# NetApp RAID DP - and disk space of parity drives

Tags: raid, storage, netapp

I've been reading:
http://community.netapp.com/t5/Tech-OnTap-Articles/Back-to-Basics-RAID-DP/ta-p/86123

That basically describes RAID-DP as diagonal parity raid. 
But there's one thing that's bothering me a bit - this example must be simplified, because it describes taking a sum. 
That's fair enough - for 'normal' parity in RAID4 and RAID5 - you do XORs rather than straight additive sums and this works because XORs are quite efficient and you can reconstruct.

If your parity is:

A xor B xor C = P

Then

P xor B xor C = A

There's just one thing that's nagging at me a bit though - The DP sum can't work that way, because if you do an 'XOR style' dual parity... you end up with an ambiguous result. You create a bunch of simultaneous equations, that allow you to figure out the relationships between bits - e.g. you know which bits are equal and not equal to each other. 
However, you end up with two valid solutions - one the 'inverse' of the other.

I assume that's why the worked example uses additive sums... but the thing that bothers me about *that* is: Your additive sum will often be a bigger number of bytes than the source. If you 'sum' 10  values a byte long, and your sum might be bigger than a byte. You could 'wrap' your sum I guess, but you still risk getting an ambiguous result.

What your parity *effectively* tells you is which bits are equal to each other and which aren't. 
But the net result is ambiguous - you can either have the 'right' answer, or an inversion of the 'right' answer.

What am I missing?

(I suspect the answer might be similar to how RAID-6 does it).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://www.netapp.com/us/media/tr-3298.pdf which has more details and references can help you understand the design?

Comment: I've been following that sort of thing, but it uses addition sums for it's illustration. The problem with that approach is - you cannot add the values of 5 bytes, and have the sum always fit in byte sized parity block. That's why - instead of addition - XORs are used for RAID4 and 5. XOR cannot work for DP though, because you get two equally valid solutions. I'm _speculating_ that the way to handle this is having a known value on e.g. byte zero of the disk.

Comment: Disks are pre-zeroed.  Did you check the theorem for these kinds of details? https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/fast04/tech/corbett/corbett.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the result not fitting for addition.  Just ignore the overflow.  There is no ambiguity.  For example, let's imagine buckets that hold a single decimal digit.

5 + 4 + 8 + 3 + 6 => 26.

Since it only holds one digit, we'll just write "6" for parity.  Now we need to reconstruct the fourth data digit.  The inverse for addition is subtraction:

6 - (5 + 4 + 8 + 6) => -17
Just add "10"s to it until you get a positive number, and 3 is the missing value.

You're right that for dual disk, you can't work on a single row and recover the information.  You must be able to read multiple rows.  [Here](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/fast04/tech/corbett/corbett.pdf) is a USENIX paper that covers an algorithm for row diagonal parity.